# Enterprise Search issue - create temporary file and delegate permissions

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, search, enterprise-search

Every minute I get below log information in AdminService file, how to avoid it and why it is?
User is in WSS_WPG group and this group has correct permissions to Index location?

> Entered
>   SPProvisioningAssistant.CreateDirectory(HardDisk:\INDEKS\Office
>   Server\Applications\699926f5-b062-48f4-91e8-a57a1039035e-crawl-0\gthrsvc,
>   Secure admin access: None) creating file share
>   gthrsvc_699926f5-b062-48f4-91e8-a57a1039035e-crawl-0 at
>   HardDisk:\INDEKS\Office
>   Server\Applications\699926f5-b062-48f4-91e8-a57a1039035e-crawl-0\gthrsvc
>   creating a share security descriptor with permissions: read ; change
>   WSS_WPG; full control created share security descriptor with SDDL
>   O:BAG:DUD:(A;;FRWPFWSD;;;S-1-5-21-2107541800-585019968-2672569830-1004)
>   deleting file share
>   gthrsvc_699926f5-b062-48f4-91e8-a57a1039035e-crawl-0 Adding
>   DOMAIN\CRAWL USER to local group WSS_WPG.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont see an error here - if everything is working, I would ignore it for now.